# Laravel: Eloquent Relationship error

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a many to many relationship between products and a product_categories tables. Now I want to create a translation table for categories.

But how do I relate them in eloquent? i am learning database relationships so forgive my ignorance.

**Here is my tables:**

```
    //languages
    Schema::create('locales', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('code', 2);
        $table->string('name');
    });

    //products
    Schema::create('products', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('thumbnail');
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    //categories
    Schema::create('product_categories', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('category');
    });

    //relationship table
    Schema::create('product_productcategory', function(Blueprint $table)
    {   
        $table->integer('product_id')->unsigned()->index(); // the id of the bear
        $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products');
        $table->integer('product_category_id')->unsigned()->index(); // the id of the picnic that this bear is at
        $table->foreign('product_category_id')->references('id')->on('product_categories');
    });

    //category translations
    Schema::create('category_translations', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');

        $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('product_categories')->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->integer('locale_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('locale_id')->references('id')->on('locales')->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->unique(['category_id', 'locale_id']);
    });
```

**Product Model:**

```
class Product extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'products';

    public function product_category() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\product_category', 'product_productcategory')->translation(1);
    }
}
```

**Product categories:**

```
class product_category extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'product_categories';

    public function product() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product', 'product_productcategory');
    }
}
```

**Category Translations**

```
class Category_Translation extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'category_translations';

    public function product_category() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\product_category');
    }
}
```

**But when i run:**

```
$product = App\Product::find(1)->first();
echo $product->product_category;
```

**I get error:**

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::translation()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not call `translation` in the Product model `category` relation (because you still interacting with the query builder), instead you should access the translation as a property on the category object:

`echo $product->product_category->first()->getTranslatedIn(1)->name;`

So you could refactor your code like this:

**Product Model:**

```
class Product extends Model
{
     protected $table = 'products';

     public function product_category() {
          return $this->belongsToMany('App\product_category', 'product_productcategory');
     }
}
```

**Product categories:**

```
class product_category extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'product_categories';

    public function product() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product', 'product_productcategory');
    }

    public function translations() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Category_Translation', 'category_translations');
    }

    // relation filtered by language (cannot be accessed as a property unless you define the parameter as optional)
    public function translatedIn($language) {
         return $this->hasOne('App\Category_Translation', 'category_id')->where('locale_id', $language);

    }

    // access translated object
    public function getTranslatedIn($language) {
        return $this->translatedIn($language)->getResults();
    }


}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. I changed my code with yours and i have the following error:
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::translatedIn()

Comment: I uploaded my project for you to check :)
Run migrate and db:seed...it will create all database tables and contents for you...ignore codes related to Articles which i just added.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/x14y2tf3xos0rbo/backend.zip?dl=0

Comment: see updated answer, I'm now getting "Machine System"

Comment: Also, for convenience, consider providing the language not as a parameter to the function, but as a global value you set somewhere else in the app

Comment: Thank you very much it is working now...But I am very confused now and my mind is not working so forgive my ignorance please... When i need to access the category name of the current product it should be something like echo $product->product_category->getTranslatedIn($currentLanguage)->name... But what i am doing now is i have to provide id of the category like product_category->first() or product_category->find()...How do i overcome this problem? Is there any problem with the design of my database?
Thank you again!!!

Comment: you have multiple categories per each product, so of course you need to specify in some way which category you want to display

Comment: Hmmm...it was supposed to be 1 category per product but multiple translatiosn per category!! Can you please point me what i have done wrong here?

Comment: You should change the relation type to belongsTo, remove the pivot table, and access the category without first()